# Query on signature

Tags: unit-testing, testing, solidity, ethers.js, decentralized-applications

My signature looks like this:

```
hash: '0xb1c360f441555b43c5c4ae25d4c145465dec04f8e7e454905ca46cffa2878358',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: '0xcbdbe7c06917401e961f8af020b24c147c2b0202b78474c1612165b5d94b5507',
  blockNumber: 16629307,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  confirmations: 1,
  from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { value: "136380605794" },
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "1000000000" },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "271761211588" },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "29025368" },
  to: '0x75b0B516B47A27b1819D21B26203Abf314d42CCE',
  value: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  nonce: 399,
  data: '0xd041723100000000000000000000000090f79bf6eb2c4f870365e785982e1f101e93b9060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000df57089febbacf7ba0bc227dafbffa9fc08a93fdc68e1e42411a14efcf23656f',
  r: '0x45fbb085fc47add41a01b41b85c2866daf7417ee79757f50d7c869f8bb74ab9e',
  s: '0x6ad6776be37df4eb2cd4cfbcbd89b686f0985e9f366d71c0442381924af326d1',
  v: 1,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 31337,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Is this

```
hash: '0xb1c360f441555b43c5c4ae25d4c145465dec04f8e7e454905ca46cffa2878358'
```

the hash value of signature?

I want to identify the hash of my signature.

Answer (score 0):

The object represents a whole signed transaction.

The signature alone is stored in properties `r`, `s`, and `v`.

Or you might be familiar with another form of the signature - a 65byte hex string (`0x` followed by 130 hex characters). That's simply these 3 values concatenated one after another.

Comment: So how can I concatenate these in hex form in js?

Comment: You can use for example ethers helper fuction `joinSignature()`: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/bytes/#utils-joinSignature

Comment: Will have to put the signature  in ```( )```??

Comment: @Hacek Correct. Example snippet: https://pastebin.com/WRERSJpc